# Unable to run React-Native UIExplorer example project

Tags: android, android-ndk, react-native, ndk-build

I've been trying to run UIExplorer project on Windows. I am getting the following error-

```
...
...
make: *** [D:\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/
armeabi-v7a/objs/reactnativejni/JExecutorToken.o] Error 2
...
...
What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib'. 
> Process 'command 'C:\android-ndk-r11b\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
...
... 
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
'C:\android-ndk-r11b\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Is there any chance to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

React Native 0.22 doesn't support the last Android NDK (r11) because it needs the prebuilt gcc 4.8 which is not included into r11.

You must use the Android NDK r10e :

- [Windows 32-bit](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86.zip)
- [Windows 64-bit](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.zip)
- [Mac OS X 64-bit](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-darwin-x86_64.zip)
- [Linux 64-bit (x86)](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.zip)

Comment: Because of of another problem I had deleted the r10e version. Thanks. It works.

Comment: This is happening for me but I am using ndk-r10e. What is "the prebuilt 4.8"?

Comment: @MichaelFulton gcc 4.8